# Асинкио экзекутор зависает хотя я ожидал таймаут

Tags: python, asyncio

Думал что задача

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import functools
import time

def executor(q):
    return time.sleep(q)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    q = 20
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, functools.partial(executor,q))
        result = await asyncio.wait_for(future, 1, loop=loop)

asyncio.run(main())
```

выпадет с ошибкой через одну секунду, но она выпадает через 20 секунд.

Comment: Если завернуть строку с wait_for в try-except: print('timeout'), то отпечатается как положено через секунду, а дальше 19 секунд будет ожидание. Видимо, отмена футуры не отменяет выполнение внутри пула, и где-то в `__exit__` идёт ожидание завершения работы пула

Comment: Попробовал заменить with на try-finally: pool.shutdown(wait=False), но питон в ответ мне отсыпал пачкой ошибок и вообще совсем завис, так что осмелюсь предположить, что отменять задачи в этом пуле процессов законного способа нет :(

Comment: вручную `cancel()` выдает True, но выпонение не прерывается

Answer (score 0):

видимо вы ожидаете такого поведения - TimeoutError через 1 сек, и дальнейшее выполнение 19 сек

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def run(func, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        return loop.run_until_complete(func(*args, **kwargs))
    finally:
        loop.close()

def executor(q):
    return time.sleep(q)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    q = 20
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, run, executor, q)
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(future, 1, loop=loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: дело в том что в ран синхронный синхронный код хотелось отрабатывать. дальнейшее выполнение какраз не нужно. хотел убить future с привязанным к ней процессом разнув таймаут еррор